How can I optimize for concurrent requests where pages may not be cached?
We have a Drupal 10 site with over 100k nodes and 200k users.
Memcache, APCU, Nginx, PHP FPM and Varnish hosted on 8 Core Machine with 64GB RAM.
It works great as long as page is already cached i.e. you could send 1000 concurrent requests to home page and it won't blink.
However, issue comes with pages which aren't cached.
Why this is an issue? Answer is the bots specially AI and other mass crawlers and you can't block them enough. A new crawler would go through 10,000 pages in a row and Drupal would start struggling.
A single crawler making one request per second to a page that's not already cached can slow the entire site down.
What we have tried:

Adding replica DB set up with up to 4 replicas - no impact
Adding more hardware - no significant impact

My suspicion is some sort of locking at play but can't find a solution here.
Drupal 10 is great but really struggling to serve even 1 unique page per second in our case.
Is there anything else we can do to cope with these rogue bots and issue is only going to get worse with more and more AI scrapers coming out every day?

Considering the scale at which you’re operating, have you taken the time to do any profiling to see why a page load takes so many resources?

yes, surprisingly no issues with single page load. Less than 30ms page generation as reported by New Relic. Node pages just have node body and a couple of blocks cached globally.

I am thinking this could be due to internal page cache because that's really the only table getting written into on every page load. It's filling with data that will likely never get used to varnish at the front?

If you have Varnish the internal page cache is of little value.

New Relic is fine for aggregate stats but if you know of a specific slow page load use xhprof or similar to get the complete profile.

My suspicion is some sort of locking at play but can't find a solution here. Did you monitor locking in real time on mysql level? Did you set the recommended transaction isolation level for Drupal sites READ COMMITTED?

@4uk4 I had READ COMMITTED set for sessions as part of settings.php but have now changed it globally as well. I have turned off statistics, internal page cache and moved lock system to Memcache.  Lets see how it goes!

This may help someone else in same position.
Drupal is a slow CMS, it gets extremely slow with lots of nodes and data.
Since Drupal 7, more focus is on caching data externally like Varnish or CDNs. Even Drupal.org runs behind varnish.
This was great until we didn't have 30 search bots and 50 AI bots who all want to crawl everything every day. You just can't protect your backend with a front proxy anymore.
Interestingly, Drupal.org has put 10sec crawl delay directive in their Robots.txt but aggressive bots like Google completely ignore it.
When you are forced to serve most of your pages uncached, I think biggest bottleneck with Drupal is the database. Even when you put all 100k pages in front proxy, stupid bots like Google will pick a random query parameter and will bust your cache for non existing pages.
In my case, what has really worked is RAID0 of 10 disks for Mariadb data directory. Sudden drop in page generation time from 120ms to just 23ms.
And ditched Memcache module for Redis.. slightly slower but no locking nightmares.
